# Lync 2010 SDK Share Application on an existing conversation

Tags: c#, sdk, lync

Is there a way to share an application on an existing open conversation window, using Lync 2010 SDK.

Every example that I have come across talks about starting a new conversation
Example: 
Walkthrough: Share an Application Process with Another User (Lync 2010 SDK) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh378559(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to "share" the applications with multiple applications using the Lync Client SDK.  I like to thing of the Lync Client SDK as an API that remote controls the Lync Client application.

This is why multiple applications using the Lync Client SDK works as the Lync Client runs as a separate process and can take remote commands from Lync Client SDK application processes.  It is also why when the Lync Client is no running why the Lync Client SDK can't do anything.

There is a "special" mode that you can run a Lync Client as a second instance of the Lync Client process without a UI called [UI suppression mode or side by side mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933224.aspx).  Useful if you wish to do something outside of the visibility of the main Lync Client or if you are crazy enough to replace the complete UI of the Lync Client.